# Passing a model object to a phtml email template in 2.4.4

Tags: email, email-templates, magento2.4.4

We have a module which sends emails to customers. To get the data in the email, we're passing it to an `html` template which then calls a `phtml` template to actually render the data, passing the data along with it.

The flow is as follows:

1. In our email sending method (in the controller) we're passing a model (a data object) to the template as variable:

```php
// ...more code...
$this->transportBuilder
    ->setTemplateIdentifier('quotation_email')
    ->setTemplateVars(['quotationRequest' => $quotationRequest])
// ...more code...
```

2. From there, we have an `html` template which then adds header and footer blocks and calls the actual `phtml` template via a layout handle:

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Your Quote Request"}}  @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{layout handle="quotation_email" quotationRequest=$quotationRequest area="frontend"}}

{{block type="cms/block" block_id="agb_email_english"}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

3. Finally, in the `phtml` email template we're retrieving the data object with `$quotation = $block->getQuotationRequest();` to use it in the template.

Up until 2.4.3 this worked without any issues. Since upgrading to 2.4.4 the template does not work anymore - the `quotationRequest` is `null` in the `phtml` template.

In the [migration guide for custom email templates](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html) it says

> As of Magento 2.3.4, custom email templates are only allowed to use scalar values for variable data. Direct calls to methods are no longer allowed.

This explains why the variable is `null` and does not contain the object when trying to retrieve it in the `phtml` template.

Now the question is, how do I properly pass the object from my controller to the `phtml` template?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, objects are sanitized and removed but array with objects in them are not. That means when I pass the data like this:

```php
$this->transportBuilder
    ->setTemplateIdentifier('quotation_email')
    ->setTemplateVars(['quotationRequest' => ['request' => $quotationRequest]])
```

I can access the object via `$block->getQuotationRequest()['request']` in the phtml template.

While this works, it does not feel like it should. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

**Edit:** The docs have a section about this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html#nested-arrays